# Working with hasMany and Multi-select

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

**Scenario**

- I have `Provider` and `Package`.
- A provider can have a number of featured packages.
- So we need a HABTM between `Provider` and `Package`
- I want to save all the providers featured packages in one shot using the `Provider::edit()` method

**Setup**
I have three models.
`Provider`
`FeaturedPackage`
`Package`

*Models*

These are setup using the '[HABTM Through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)', which should not be confused with HABTM. So the relationships are as follows.

`Provider` hasMany `FeaturedPackage`
`FeaturedPackage` belongsTo `Provider`
`Package` hasMany `FeaturedPackage`
`FeaturedPackage` belongsTo `Package`

*Controller*

```
public function admin_edit($id) {
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Provider->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
// snip
```

*View*

```
echo $this->Form->input('FeaturedPackages', array('type' => 'select', 'multiple' => true, 'options' => $packages));
```

**The issue**
I'm not sure how to save multiple variable numbers of `hasMany` records from one side of the relationship. I know from reading the book that the expected data array should be numerically indexed beneath the model.

However I'm not sure what to name my field to get the data formatted correctly.

I am unable to bake the view as it seems to ignore the `hasMany` and not even add a field for it.

**Field names I've tried**
FeaturedPackage
FeaturedPackage.FeaturedPackage
FeaturedPackage.package_id
FeaturedPackage..package_id
FeaturedPackage.[].package_id
FeaturedPackage.package_id][

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this using a data massage method in my model, which is called from the controller.

This goes through and updates the array submitted from the form to match what is expected by the save.

I blogged my solution, http://jedistirfry.co.uk/blog/2013-08/how-to-create-hasmanythrough-multi-selects/

Comment: Dear Downvoter. Please can you leave a comment explaining why you downvoted so that I can improve my answer. Love and hugs.